# Unkown error in Flask when sending ajax request even though duplicate request from other function works fine

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, raspberry-pi

ok so I am new to python and flask and find it very useful to run a webapp for my RBpi.

I originally coded the app in HTML and used javascript for the logic but since I now have a "completed" app (this stage) I decided to move on improving the functionality and ability.

I am more familiar with PHP but like the ease of use and ability python is giving me for writing backend frameworks to the app IE cronjobs etc.

I have attempted to merge my current code to provide persistent variables by storing them in the python code. I have attempted to do this by using an ajax request to send a URL with data strings and then use that data to store a global variable in my app.py when ran.

when I send the data using an on click event:

```
<script> //set timer buttons down

function downtime1(){
     if(window.time1 !== 60)
            {
    window.time1 = window.time1 - 60;
    window.times1 = window.time1 / 60;
    $.ajax({url: '/boxtimes/1/'+window.time1,});
    document.getElementById("button1time").innerHTML = times1;
    document.getElementById("button1timeset").innerHTML = times1;
    }
}
    
function downtime2(){
         if(window.time2 !== 60)
            {
    window.time2 = window.time2 - 60;
    window.times2 = window.time2 / 60;
    $.ajax({url: '/boxtimes/2/'+window.time2,});
    document.getElementById("button2time").innerHTML = times2;
    document.getElementById("button2timeset").innerHTML = times2;
}
}
function downtime3(){
         if(window.time3 !== 60)
            {
    window.time3 = window.time3 - 60;
    window.times3 = window.time3 / 60;
    $.ajax({url: '/boxtimes/3/'+window.time3,});
    document.getElementById("button3time").innerHTML = times3;
    document.getElementById("button3timeset").innerHTML = times3;
}}
    </script>
```

To my app.py function

```
@app.route("/boxtimes/<boxnumber>/<time>")
def timerbtns(boxnumber,time):
    global time3
    global time2
    global time1
    global timeset

    timeset = time
    if boxnumber == '3':
        time3 = timeset
    if boxnumber == '2':
        time2 = timeset
    if boxnumber == '1':
        time1 = timeset

        TemplateData = {
              'lc1'  : lc1,
              'lc2'  : lc2,
              'lc3'  : lc3,
              'lc4'  : lc4,
              'lc5'  : lc5,
              'lc6'  : lc6,
              'lc7'  : lc7,
              'lc8'  : lc8,
              'crnttime'  : crnttime,
              'timerstatus'  : timerstatus,
              'time1'  : time1,
              'time2'  : time2,
              'time3'  : time3,
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **TemplateData)
```

It is interpreted fine and I get no error clicking it multiple times to increase the time up or down.

---

When I send data using a click event:

```
<script> //light1 control
    window.lc1 = {{ lc1  }};
    
    if(window.lc1 == 3){ document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";};
    if (window.lc1 == 2){ document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent"; document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";};
    if (window.lc1 == 1){ document.getElementById("slc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                        document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent"; document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";};
    if (window.lc1 == 0){ 
    document.getElementById("slc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
    document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
    document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
        };
    

// change light setting

    
    function lightbutton1() { 
    
    if(window.lc1 == 3){ $.ajax({url: '/light/light1/3',});
         window.lc1 = 2;
    document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
     }
    else if (window.lc1 == 2){ $.ajax({url: '/light/light1/2',});
        window.lc1 = 1;
    document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        }
    else if (window.lc1 == 1){ $.ajax({url: '/light/light1/1',});
        window.lc1 = 0;
    document.getElementById("slc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        }
    else if (window.lc1 == 0){ $.ajax({url: '/light/light1/0',});
        window.lc1 = 3;
    document.getElementById("slc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
    document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
    document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
        }
    
    };
</script>
```

From a fresh page load, it initially has no error and sends the ajax URL fine according to the log, but it won't change the element display. I must click it a second time for the button to change its display background color, and on the second(and any future clicks) it will change the display and send an error in the log.

the function in app.py it uses is :

```
@app.route("/light/<lightnumber>/<status>")
def setrelays(lightnumber, status):
    global lc1
    global lc2
    global lc3
    global lc4
    global lc5
    global lc6
    global lc7
    global lc8

    if lightnumber == 'light1':
            switch1 = A1
            switch2 = B1
            lc1 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light2':
            switch1 = A2
            switch2 = B2
            lc2 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light3':
            switch1 = A3
            switch2 = B3
            lc3 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light4':
            switch1 = A4
            switch2 = B4
            lc4 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light5':
            switch1 = A5
            switch2 = B5
            lc5 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light6':
            switch1 = A6
            switch2 = B6
            lc6 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light7':
            switch1 = A7
            switch2 = B7
            lc7 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light8':
            switch1 = A8
            switch2 = B8
            lc8 = status

    if status == "0": #off
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)
    if status == "1": #on low
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)
    if status == "2": #on medium
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)
    if status == "3": #on high
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)

        templateData = {
              'lc1'  : lc1,
              'lc2'  : lc2,
              'lc3'  : lc3,
              'lc4'  : lc4,
              'lc5'  : lc5,
              'lc6'  : lc6,
              'lc7'  : lc7,
              'lc8'  : lc8,
              'crnttime'  : crnttime,
              'timerstatus'  : timerstatus,
              'time1'  : time1,
              'time2'  : time2,
              'time3'  : time3,          
    }
             
    return render_template('index.html', **TemplateData)
```

the log from terminal while running the app.py

```
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:19] "GET /boxtimes/1/1140 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:19] "GET /boxtimes/1/1080 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:19] "GET /boxtimes/1/1020 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:19] "GET /boxtimes/1/960 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:20] "GET /boxtimes/1/900 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:36] "GET /light/light1/3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.19 - - [23/Apr/2021 22:06:37] "GET /light/light1/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/app/app.py", line 172, in setrelays
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'templateData' referenced before assignment
```

Download the full HTML code here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zSYzo8WQPHp1bvsvqwGUL1Cp9hkmGpuf/view?usp=sharing

Here is the full app.py code

```
'''
    Raspberry Pi GPIO Status and Control
'''
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#define actuators GPIOs
A1 = 13
A2 = 19
A3 = 26
A4 = 13
A5 = 19
A6 = 26
A7 = 13
A8 = 19
B1 = 26
B2 = 13
B3 = 19
B4 = 26
B5 = 26
B6 = 13
B7 = 19
B8 = 26
#initialize GPIO status variables
lc1 = 3
lc2 = 3
lc3 = 3
lc4 = 3
lc5 = 3
lc6 = 3
lc7 = 3
lc8 = 3
# Define timer Variables
crnttime = 0
timerstatus = 0
# Define default button times
time1 = 1200
time2 = 1800
time3 = 2400

# Define led pins as output
GPIO.setup(A1, GPIO.OUT)   
GPIO.setup(A2, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(A3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(A4, GPIO.OUT)   
GPIO.setup(A5, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(A6, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(A7, GPIO.OUT)   
GPIO.setup(A8, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(B1, GPIO.OUT)   
GPIO.setup(B2, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(B3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(B4, GPIO.OUT)   
GPIO.setup(B5, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(B6, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(B7, GPIO.OUT)   
GPIO.setup(B8, GPIO.OUT) 
# turn leds OFF 
GPIO.output(A1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(A2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(A3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(A4, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(A5, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(A6, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(A7, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(A8, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B4, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B5, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B6, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B7, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(B8, GPIO.LOW)
    
@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Read Status and render info
    templateData = {
              'lc1'  : lc1,
              'lc2'  : lc2,
              'lc3'  : lc3,
              'lc4'  : lc4,
              'lc5'  : lc5,
              'lc6'  : lc6,
              'lc7'  : lc7,
              'lc8'  : lc8,
              'crnttime'  : crnttime,
              'timerstatus'  : timerstatus,
              'time1'  : time1,
              'time2'  : time2,
              'time3'  : time3,
    }

    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
# parsing light button and setting gpio pins to correct setting 
@app.route("/light/<lightnumber>/<status>")
def setrelays(lightnumber, status):
    global lc1
    global lc2
    global lc3
    global lc4
    global lc5
    global lc6
    global lc7
    global lc8

    if lightnumber == 'light1':
            switch1 = A1
            switch2 = B1
            lc1 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light2':
            switch1 = A2
            switch2 = B2
            lc2 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light3':
            switch1 = A3
            switch2 = B3
            lc3 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light4':
            switch1 = A4
            switch2 = B4
            lc4 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light5':
            switch1 = A5
            switch2 = B5
            lc5 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light6':
            switch1 = A6
            switch2 = B6
            lc6 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light7':
            switch1 = A7
            switch2 = B7
            lc7 = status
    if lightnumber == 'light8':
            switch1 = A8
            switch2 = B8
            lc8 = status

    if status == "0": #off
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)
    if status == "1": #on low
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)
    if status == "2": #on medium
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)
    if status == "3": #on high
        GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(switch2, GPIO.HIGH)

        templateData = {
              'lc1'  : lc1,
              'lc2'  : lc2,
              'lc3'  : lc3,
              'lc4'  : lc4,
              'lc5'  : lc5,
              'lc6'  : lc6,
              'lc7'  : lc7,
              'lc8'  : lc8,
              'crnttime'  : crnttime,
              'timerstatus'  : timerstatus,
              'time1'  : time1,
              'time2'  : time2,
              'time3'  : time3,          
    }
             
    return render_template('index.html', **TemplateData)
# parsing light button and setting gpio pins to correct setting 
@app.route("/boxtimes/<boxnumber>/<time>")
def timerbtns(boxnumber,time):
    global time3
    global time2
    global time1
    global timeset

    timeset = time
    if boxnumber == '3':
        time3 = timeset
    if boxnumber == '2':
        time2 = timeset
    if boxnumber == '1':
        time1 = timeset

        TemplateData = {
              'lc1'  : lc1,
              'lc2'  : lc2,
              'lc3'  : lc3,
              'lc4'  : lc4,
              'lc5'  : lc5,
              'lc6'  : lc6,
              'lc7'  : lc7,
              'lc8'  : lc8,
              'crnttime'  : crnttime,
              'timerstatus'  : timerstatus,
              'time1'  : time1,
              'time2'  : time2,
              'time3'  : time3,
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **TemplateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

my question is what have i done wrong? a d how do i1 fix the error in sending the data to my app, and why wont the HTML change  on my first button click event? and info would be greatly appreciated . Note i have  not implemented some of the persistence function that i have previously put in the HTML or app.py yet like crnttime or timerstatus.

Comment: Looks like an indent issue on `def setrelays(lightnumber, status):`.  `templateData` is inside your `if` block. It should be outside if it's part of the render.

Comment: why thank you sir very helpful still haven't learned python syntax/formatting yet that was frustrating me for hours now how do I upvote a comment lol

Answer (score 0):

My templateData was indented wrong as ksankar pointed out if he posts his comment as an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Also I found that I needed to place the code

```
    window.lc1 = {{ lc1  }};
    
    if (window.lc1 == 3){ 
    document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    };
    if (window.lc1 == 2){ 
    document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent"; 
    document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    };
    if (window.lc1 == 1){ 
    document.getElementById("slc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent"; 
    document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    };
    if (window.lc1 == 0){ 
    document.getElementById("slc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
    document.getElementById("mlc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
    document.getElementById("llc1").style.backgroundColor = "#DB402B";
    };
```

in the head of the document to make it not interfere with the first button press event hope this helps anyone.